# How to pass a temporary vector by const reference?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

What do i need to do to the following code in order for it to output the values of `A` and `B`? You can edit and compile it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1bbc53b942cd4b4b16bd486ce1916d59-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51) if you like.

```
typedef const std::vector<int>& t;

class SomeClass
{
    t data;
public:
    SomeClass(t _data) : data(_data) {}
    void disp()
    {
        for (auto v : data)
            std::cout << v << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
};

int A = 1;
int B = 2;

SomeClass f = SomeClass( {A, B} );
f.disp();

A = 456;
f.disp();
```

Comment: are you sure that `{A, B}`is not a temporary object (vector) and it's not destroyed after constructor of `SomeClass` is exited?

Comment: Binding a temporary in a constructor does not extend lifetimes. Don't use reference members if you're not totally comfortable with this.

Comment: you have `typedef const std::vector<int>& t` your class member cannot be `t datatype` change it to `std::vector<int> data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like you want it to be possible to update the elements of the vector from outside the class.

However, before getting to this, there is the problem that you are storing a reference to a temporary object (a `vector` made of `{1, 2}`). This object gets deallocated when the call `SomeClass( {A, B} )` completes.

There are three ways to solve this:

1. If you know the lifetime of the `SomeClass` object, you can have a copy to the vector outside of the `SomeClass` instance `f`. For example, if `f` will only exist for the duration of the function that created it, you can do something like

   ```
   std::vector<int>   aVector({A, B});
   SomeClass          f = SomeClass(aVector);
   ```

   The creating function "owns" `aVector`, and `f` has a reference to it.
2. You can have the `SomeClass` instance make a copy of the vector. For this, you can pass the vector by reference, but make a copy in the constructor:

   ```
   class SomeClass
   {
       std::vector<int>    data;
     public:
       SomeClass(const std::vector<int> &_data) : data(_data) {}
       ...
   }
   ```

   `f` now "owns" its own copy of the vector. However, you will now be unable to change the value of the elements from outside the object, so you will want to either store pointers inside the vector (`std::vector<int*>`) or provide a method in the class for changing contents, if that's an option.
3. You can use move semantics (C++11) to make sure that the argument vector's internal storage is not copied, but instead reassigned to `SomeClass::data` during construction:

   ```
   class SomeClass
   {
       std::vector<int>    data;
     public:
       SomeClass(std::vector<int> &&_data) : data(std::move(_data)) {}
       ...
   }
   ```

   As before, `f` "owns" the vector. Again, it is not possible to alter the contents of `f.data` from outside the object, so you will want to store pointers in the vector or provide a method.

In none of these cases, as they are written above, will you be able to change the contents of the vector by updating `A`. This is because a copy of `A` is made when creating the vector, and that copy will keep the value `1`.

In cases (2) and (3), to be able to update the vector by updating `A`, you have to store pointers in the vector, as mentioned. You can also do this in case (1). Note that when storing pointers, you need to make sure that the memory they are pointing to persists for as long as you might use the pointers – essentially the same ownership problem as you are solving with the vector itself.

In case (1), you can also update the contents of the vector by updating `aVector[0]`, because `f` has a reference to `aVector`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to use pointers, and holding a real vector instead of a reference in your class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
//This is now a vector type, not a reference to vector. Also, it contains
// pointer to int instead of a copy.
typedef const std::vector<int *> t; 

class SomeClass
{
    t data;
public:

// We pass the vector by reference here.

    SomeClass(t & _data) : data(_data) {}
    void disp()
    {
        for (auto v : data)
            std::cout << *v << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
};

int A = 1;
int B = 2;

// We have to pass the address of A and B here.
SomeClass f = SomeClass( {&A, &B} );
f.disp();

A = 456;
f.disp();
}
```

However, since we hold pointers on A and B (which are locals), as soon as A and B are discarded (the next '}' basically), the vector will hold pointers to invalid values, and this is BAD.

On your example, your class is discarded with A and B, so it's OK, but if your class survived longer than A and B, the behaviour of disp() would be undefined (SIGSEGV probably).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are holding a reference to a temporary in your class, and dereferencing it triggers an undefined behavior. You need to change typedef to a vector(remove &) and add in in the constructor instead : SomeClass(t& _data) so that you keep an actual object in your class and accept constructor argument as reference

Answer (score 0):

You need a more permanent vector for your example to work.

The class as you put it is okay, but must document itself to *store* the passed reference, so REQUIRE argument that has lifetime spanning love of SomeClass instance.

Your current invocation fails there: you pass in a vector that is created as temporary and gets destroyed right at end of that line. As you get to next line, your f holds a dangling reference, and using it puts you to undefined behavior land.

To fix vreate the vector in a separate line and pass that to the SomeClass ctor.

Answer (score 0):

There are three mistakes.

1. It's not initializer lists.
2. f is not assigned you expected.
3. data don't have address of the values

So:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef const std::vector<int*>& t;

class SomeClass
{
    t data;
public:
    SomeClass(t& _data) : data(_data) {}
    void disp()
    {
        for (auto v : data)
            std::cout << *v << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
};

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int A = 1;
    int B = 2;
    t v = {&A, &B};

    SomeClass f(v);
    f.disp();

    A = 456;
    f.disp();
    return 0;
}
```